# Appending String While Databinding in Silverlight xaml Question

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding, append, concatenation

I have a control which accepts a string but when displaying it i want to append "Hello" to that string right in xaml how do i do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind to the property and use the StringFormat:

```
<TextBlock Text=”{Binding Path=UserName, StringFormat=’Hello \{0\} ’}“/>
```

Some more info can be found here:
http://www.designersilverlight.com/2010/05/28/silverlight-4-binding-and-stringformat-in-xaml/